# New house, found 4 terminals with one twisted pair connected to each?

Tags: ethernet

In my new house I've found a set of four terminals with one ethernet cable connected to all of them.  The cable is split so that there is only one twisted pair connected to each terminal.  What on earth is this for?

Thank you

--
Edit:
[image]

[Link to larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iNAb.jpg)

Comment: It's hard to tell without a picture.

Comment: @chrylis Good call, added!

Comment: What are they connected to? This looks like a basic installation using 8-wire cable to run 4 2-wire phone lines.

Comment: @xtraorange, sadly home wiring / networking is off-topic.  I asked the [diy.SE] moderators for a migration there, but they declined since it's not really your project per-SE (all you're trying to do is figure out what it is).  The DIY mod's comment was "it's anybody's guess, but it looks like someone was just trying to extend four phone lines over a Cat5 wire" (which was my analysis of the situation too).

Comment: @chrylis - No idea, if I knew I'd have a better idea of what they are for.  All I was able to locate was the other end of the lower wire, which is connected to nothing... no idea where those beige ones run to, somewhere under the flooring I couldn't follow.

Comment: @MikePennington - Sorry about that Mike, I thought I had the right place.  Feel free to close/delete the question... it sounds like some sort of phone line set up is the purpose here.  Thanks for letting it remain until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're attached to the blue pair, which is the center pins. So that would be "phone" (or DSL), but why it's RJ45 (4 pair) instead of RJ11/12 (single pair) is unknown.  My only advice would be to trace out where they go / what's attached (assuming there is anything still there.)

(Note: I've seen some truly odd setups around PBX's. But there's no reason to have a PBX in most houses.)

Comment: I originally tried tracing them, but they go into the floor where I can't follow, and I wasn't able to find anything that might suggest they were connected there.  I believe you're right though.  This place is an old church, so I bet it has something to do with that.

Comment: an old church, eh?  Perhaps you just located the hotline to heaven